# Object does not support property or method 'endsWith' in IE in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react-scripts version 5.0.1 in package.json
before I updated to 5.0.1 it was working fine in IE.

Now I am getting

> object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'

error

[image]

Comment: Does a search for `.endsWith` in the source find anything?

Answer (score 0):

replace it with this

```
const str = 'Is this a question?';
console.log(str.slice(str2.length -1) === '?' );
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: 1. That would solve only a single instance of the issue. A polyfill would be better. 2. `str2` is not defined, but even if you corrected it to `str`, it would be unnecessary since `slice(-1)` does the same thing.